# Can't connect to sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

**Im trying to install asp.net membership system on a remote sql server but this error shows up:**

Setup failed.

Exception:
Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

---

### Details of failure

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
ClientConnectionId:24557c63-f9b1-498c-bd1d-0d678f29f795
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install)
   at System.Web.Management.ConfirmPanel.Execute()
```

**I have the same problem with connecting to remote sql server from vs2012**

Comment: how are you trying to connect to the remote SQL Server?
Through code, or Management Studio??

Comment: i can connect to the remote instance so fast through SQL SERVER Management Studio but when i try to connect to it through visual studio or use aspnet_regsql it gives me the above error

Comment: what if you add teh connection string to the web.config, and then through the code, make the connection??

Comment: found the problem, it was caused by an external application interfering the connection, "internet download manager", i uninstalled the application and then it all went well.

Comment: @Mahdi , How did you find that this was caused by Internet download manager. I am having this problem in one of our production box. I can't randomly uninstall software there. Is there a way to find the software that cause this issue. Appreciate your timely  help.

Comment: @Mahdi: Please post your solution as an answer, so that others facing the same issue quickly see a possible resolution. Ideally, along with an explanation of how you found out that an external application was interfering. (Other visitors might not expect to find an answer in the comments section and therefore never see your solution.)

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur if one or more of the following conditions is true:

- SQL Server is not configured to accept remote connections.
- The necessary protocols for SQL Server are not enabled on either the SQL Server computer or the SQL Server client computer that is running BizTalk Server.

Following these steps may resolve this problem:

- The **SQL Server Surface Area Configuration** tool is not available on SQL Server 2008. To enable remote connections for SQL Server on a SQL Server 2008 computer follow the instructions in the SQL Server 2008 online help.
- Use the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** tool to enable the **TCP/IP** and/or the **Named Pipes** protocols on the SQL Server computer.

  1. Click **Start**, point to **All Programs**, and click **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
  2. Click to expand **SQL Server Network Configuration** and then click **Protocols for MSSQLSERVER**.
  3. Right-click the **TCP/IP** protocol and then click **Enable**.
  4. Right-click the **Named Pipes** protocol and then click **Enable**.
  5. Close the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** tool.
- Use the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** tool to enable the **TCP/IP** and/or the **Named Pipes** protocols on the SQL Server client computer that is running BizTalk Server.

  1. Click **Start**, point to **All Programs**, and click **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
  2. Click to expand **SQL Server Network Configuration** and then click **ClientProtocols**.
  3. Right-click the **TCP/IP** protocol and then click **Enable**.
  4. Right-click the **Named Pipes** protocol and then click **Enable**.
  5. Close the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** tool.

**Note:** Ensure that at least one of the protocols on the SQL Server client computer that is running BizTalk Server matches the protocols enabled on the SQL Server computer.